# Can I access this control with UI Automation?

Tags: ui-automation, revit, microsoft-ui-automation

I am trying to access this list of checkboxes in an Autodesk Revit dialog with UI Automation. But when I look at the dialog with Inspect and UISpy, the list or checkboxes are not shown. There is an "Add selection to:" pane and the scrollbars that scroll the checkbox list, but not the checkbox list. Is there any way to access these controls?

[image: it]

Answer (score 0):

Is the list dynamically populated? If so can you try to set an Automation ID for the controls and check. I had similar issue with a custom controller and it works that way.

Comment: Thanks @tenne could you explain more about how I can get the Automation ID for the controls?

Comment: I'm not the developer of this dialog, so I don't know how I can set any IDs. I am a 3rd party developer trying to push buttons in the dialog using Windows Automation.

Comment: Import "System.Windows.Automation" for UI automation. If the controller constructor support only setters, do the following. element.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "automation_ID");